# Bower Install Error In Azure App Services

Tags: node.js, azure, bower, azure-web-app-service, bower-install

[image]

I was running my bower package manager in Azure App Services. When I ran the following command:

```
bower install
```

or even

```
bower install --force
```

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [custom the deployment task](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to achieve your requirements.

Generally speaking, you can try the following steps,

1. install azure x-platform command via `npm install azure-cli -g`
2. run custom deployment script generator via `azure site deploymentscript --node`
3. This command will create 2 files named `.deployment` and `deploy.cmd`
4. In `deploy.cmd` file include below lines of code after installing `npm` packages. Change bower install folder based on your requirement.

   ```
   IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\public\bower.json" (

   pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\public"

   call ..\node_modules\.bin\bower install

   IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

   popd

   )
   ```
5. Then next you deploy your application to Azure via Git, it will run the deployment script which will run `bower install` script in your application.

You can refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/01/25/using-bower-in-node-js-azure-webapps/ for more detailed info. And here is a sample on Github about [bower sample on Azure](https://github.com/prashanthmadi/Azure-bower-sample).